# Does an option exist in Chrome which prevents the "Download in progress" dialog from appearing?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, automation

I'm creating an automated test where I open Chrome and it verifies that a certain file becomes available for download. Assuming this is the case, I want to then have Chrome close completely, but the dialog below is preventing this:

[image: Chrome download in progress dialog.]

Is there a setting in Chrome which suppresses this dialog? Or failing that, is there some way to reference the dialog and if necessary close it or click `Yes, exit Chrome` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution of suppressing the dialog, but you can try the following:

- Configure your "automated test" to send the input "ESC" from keyboard when the dialog appear, perhaps it will solve your problem in an easy way.